# Can I rename the values in a MySQL ENUM column in one query?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Suppose I have a Database table with an `ENUM('value_one','value_two')`.
I want to change that to an `ENUM('First value','Second value')`. I an currently doing that as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `column` ENUM('value_one','value_two','First value','Second value');
UPDATE `table` SET `column`='First Value' WHERE `column`='value_one';
UPDATE `table` SET `column`='Second Value' WHERE `column`='value_two';
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `column` ENUM('First value','Second value');
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, E.G. a way to accomplish this with a  *single* `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The follolwing technique I am about to show you will require guts of steel.

Given the following criteria

- datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`
- table is `mydb.mytb`
- enum column called is called `enum_col`
- engine is MyISAM

Here is a death-defying crack at it:

1. `CREATE TABLE mydb.mybt LIKE mydb.mytb;`
2. `ALTER TABLE mydb.mybt MODIFY enum_col ENUM('First value','Second value');`
3. `SET wait_timeout=86400; SET interactive_timeout=86400;`
4. `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`
5. In a separate OS/SSH Session, swap the .frm files

   - `$ mv /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytb.frm /var/lib/mysql/mydb/myxx.frm`
   - `$ mv /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mybt.frm /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytb.frm`
   - `$ mv /var/lib/mysql/mydb/myxx.frm /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mybt.frm`
6. `UNLOCK TABLES;`
7. `DROP TABLE mydb.mybt;`

That's it !!!

CAVEAT : I CANNOT TAKE CREDIT FOR THIS !

This technique comes from ["High Performance MySQL : Optimization, Backups, Replication, and more", Pages 146-148](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716) under the Subheading **Speeding Up ALTER TABLE**. Page 147 Paragraph 1 says:

> The technique we are about to demonstrate is unsupported,
>   undocumented, and may not work. Use it at your risk. We advise you to
>   back up you data first!

Give it a try ! (Please let us know how it turned out)

**UPDATE 2011-10-05 17:49 EDT**

If the table is MyISAM and you have enough space in production and a straight-up downtime window, try this:

1. `service mysql restart --skip-networking`
2. In a separate OS/SSH Session, make a copy of the table

   - `cp /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytb.frm /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytbplay.frm`
   - `cp /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytb.MYD /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytbplay.MYD`
   - `cp /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytb.MYI /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytbplay.MYI`

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` will automatically detect the presence of the new table called `mydb.mytbplay`.

1. Perform the guts-of-steel algorithm on `mydb.mytbplay`
2. You test the integrity of `mydb.mytbplay`

If you are satisfied

1. `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytb RENAME mydb.mytb_backup;`
2. `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytbplay RENAME mydb.mytb;`
3. `service mysql restart`

Give it a try!

Comment: +1 for an ingenious answer! I will not, however, be giving this a try and letting you know how it turned out as the question refers to an upgrade script for all my customer's live, production databases ;-) I may, however, try this on a development environment just for fun. But with that warning I'd never run this in production!

Answer (score 6):

## A simple solution would be:

1- add a new column:

`` ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `enum2` ENUM('First value', 'Second value') NOT NULL AFTER `enum`; ``

2- Copy the value of column to enum2 with replacements:

`` UPDATE `table` SET enum2=REPLACE(`column`, "value_one", "new value") ``

3- Drop column `column`, rename `enum` to `column`.

***NOTE***: this question back to 2011-10-05, my solution is valid for MYSQL 4.1 and newer (AFAIK)

Comment: While this sounds like a good solution (and not nearly as nerve-wracking as the accepted answer!), it's worth noting that step 3 does require at least one `ALTER TABLE` statement, and the OP was looking for something that only required one. Again, that said, it seems like a perfectly standard, solid solution.