# Advantages and Disadvantages to using ENUM vs Integer types?

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

Lets say in some random table, you have a column named *status*. It's real-world values would be either *enabled* or *disabled*.

Is it better for this column's data type to be an int/bool (1 or zero) or to use `ENUM` with the values being `enabled` and `disabled`? What are the advantages or disadvantages?

Let's say instead of just two valid status's, you have 4 or 10 or even more? Do the advantages and disadvantages sway to one side or the other as the number of required values increases?

Comment: This question should be bookmarked by all MySQL Developers because it can become a source of either heartbreak or triumph. +1 !!!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[I found a very bizarre but informative article](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) about 8 reasons why one should not use ENUM.

Even without the article, I know

- [there is no easy method for adding new values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/can-i-rename-the-values-in-a-mysql-enum-column-in-one-query/6548#6548), some techniques are very high risk
- numbers should never be used
- only use strings (@DTest already mentioned this in his answer)

Comment: Even though the other answer(s) in this thread are very informative, I'm marking this one as the answer because of the very helpful article.

Comment: +1 You can't reuse the member-list of an ENUM column in other tables. ENUM has limited portability to other DBMS.

Comment: What could I have to do if I have a field has relations with other records of the same table? For example, suppose `units` model for a shop items where each record should have property for its related units `composition`. i.e Ton, Kg, gm

Comment: Nothing bizarre about that article - it's great! I think it was this post that put me on to why they're bad! I gave it a +1!

Comment: The article suggests to use a good old table, instead of ENUM types. Should we add this to the answer?

Comment: @Utku No need to add that information to this answer because the question asked about the pros and cons of using ENUM. Such an answer should be posted separately as a suggestion or an alternative.

Comment: In 2022 enum values can be added and removed easily, without downtime in most database engines. And MySQL strict mode prevents invalid ENUM values from being set.   The other downsides still apply.

Answer (score 42):

Well, first off we have the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html). I'm going to assume you meant a tinyint (instead of int).

- ENUM takes 1 byte (if under 255 values) or 2 bytes (up to maximum of 65,535
- TinyInt takes 1 byte (maximum of 255 values)
- Boolean is a synonym for TinyInt

So, on the surface, they're all the same. ENUM does take up some metadata for the string value associated with it though ([older src](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,3587,3590#msg-3590))

I would say as you add more values though, any advantage starts to swing away from `ENUM`. Especially if you add the values after the table is already in use, because you have to alter the table structure to accommodate.

What is the advantage of using an `ENUM`? A string representation of what the value means. That's it, as far as I'm concerned. How valuable that is depends on your application.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the only real advantage : String representation. Everything else is a wash going forward.

Answer (score 20):

I find ENUM is a short form definition of a code table.  Its main advantage is that it avoids the code required to join and show the code description.  It also eases setting the values if they arrive in string form.

I find it has the following disadvantages:

- No capability for additional metadata about the code.
- Difficult to add or disable values.  (Disabling codes can be accomplished with a trigger and expiry field.)
- I18n in the database can not be done.
- Not reusable across tables.