# INT or CHAR for a Type Field

Tags: sql-server, database-design, datatypes

What is the best design for a table, a `Type` field that is of `int` or `char(1)`?  In other words, given this schema:

```
create table Car
(
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    Description varchar(100) not null,
    VehType .... not null
)
```

Is it more efficient (performance wise) for `VehType` to be an `int` or a `char(1)`?  Say you have five types of cars, should you use the incrementing values 0 -> 4, or characters for the types (say; 'v', 's', 'c', 't', 'm')?

If it is any more than that, I'd use a separate Type table and have a foreign key relationship, but I don't see the need for that.

I notice that the `sys.objects` catalog view uses a character for the `type` field.  Is there a reason for that?  Am I just grabbing at thin air here, and is it whatever I'm more comfortable with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd typically use tinyint which is 1 byte too

- char(1) will be slightly slower because comparing uses collation
- confusion: what is S: SUV or [Saloon or Sedan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedan_%28automobile%29) or Sports?
- using a letter limits you as you add more types. See last point.
- every system I've seen has more then one client eg reporting. The logic of changing V, S into "Van", "SUV" etc will need repeated. Using a lookup table means it is a simple JOIN
- extendibility: add one more type ("F" for "[Flying car](http://www.terrafugia.com/)") you can one row to a lookup table or change a lot of code and constraints. And your client code too because this has to know what V, S, F etc are
- maintenance: logic is in 3 places: database constraint, database code and client code. With a lookup and foreign key,it can be in one place

On the plus side of using a single letter... er, don't see any

Note: there is a related [MySQL question about Enums](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6962/630). The recommendation is to use a lookup table there too.

Comment: great points.  It makes me wonder why others do use char(1) (like sys.objects).

Comment: sys.objects has a legacy going back to Sybase and early versions of SQL Server http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Genesis If you look the system objects you can see codes not IDs all over: but less so in the new DMVs. As for other folk except MS? Think RDBMS and not OO/Enums and it makes sense to use Lookups.

Comment: ok, I agree.  Thanks for making that clear.  So is it a pretty accurate statement that there is no real over-engineering with relational integrity and lookup tables?  I mean, in this case with storing a  handful of records in a lookup table and referencing them in a consuming table, would the previous statement be accurate?

Comment: Correct, it isn't over engineering.

Comment: "need a check constraint to enforce, rather then foreign key" -- I don't see how this makes a difference either way. The rule of thumb is whether the domain is small and stable (and whether you are using mySQL :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: it should be folded into the maintenance point

Comment: @onedaywhen: It makes a difference wether you look at the different types as data or as static set of values that never will change. If you use a type table you can just add another type to the table without the need to change the business rules in the database and in the application.

Comment: @Guffa: I deliberately used the word "stable" rather than "static" or its derivatives.

Comment: "it should be folded into the maintenance point" -- excuse my ignorance but what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but about the last point; surely a primary key column can be a CHAR(1) just as well as an INT? Either would be usable in a JOIN.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Yes, of course you could use a char as key for the type, but you don't really gain anything by it. You still have the confusion and limitation issues that gbn mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Correct, if it was *just* a key. But OP intends it to mean something like "v" or "s". Note, we aren't on about self describing and complete natural keys like currency codes (EUR, USD, GBP, CHF etc).

Answer (score 3):

Just as an complement to great [gbn's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/int-or-char-for-a-type-field/6988#6988).

Maybe you could create something like that:

```
create table dbo.VehicleType
(
    VehicleTypeId int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Code char(3) null
) 
go 

create table Car
(
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    Description varchar(100) not null,
    VehTypeId int not null ,
    foreign key FKTypeOfCar(VehTypeId) referenctes dbo.VehicleType (VehicleTypeId) 
)
go
```

So you can do as you please with your enum while mantaining relational integrity (using an foreign key). With the `code` column you can use your char codes at will, so it will become documented on the database (and you can extract the code info directly from DB, without an convoluted transformation on application code for an systems integration).

Comment: Do you mean to allow a `null` code?

Comment: Yeah, code is optional to allow represent an vehicle type that is not codified yet.

Comment: Why people like to stay deleting comment? Is pretty annoying.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo - If a comment is obsolete (e.g. "I'll edit that in to my answer" and then you actually do so) then it's good to clean up the comments that no longer apply.

Comment: @Fabricio sorry I should have checked with you first about the comments.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the `null` though - only one null will be allowed due to the unique constraint. Is that really useful? Maybe it is I just want to be sure I understand...

Comment: Sincerely, this table will be much more useful without that unique constraint... (Second edit)

Comment: I would suggest adding an "Unclassified" type to your type table and making the default value of your VehTypeId field that unclassified value, rather than allowing a null value in the foreign key field.

It's generally bad practice to make "null" have a valid business meaning.