# change encoding of database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8

Tags: mysql

I have an huge database in `latin1_swedish_ci`. Now i need to convert all data to `utf8` collation.

My question is about the consistency of the information. When I do this change it is possible corrupt the data that is in database?

something like this:

```
mysql> alter database user_db default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

there is any risk of changing the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any stored procedures that use database defaults, you must drop and recreate those stored procedures.

If the [ALTER DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html) command runs quickly, chances are the tables were not altered.

You may have to run [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) on all your tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name [COLLATE collation_name];
```

Comment: I don't know, but I gave a +1 for being a good question.  My sense is that Rolando is right, changing the databases default collation would only affect new tables being created, you'll still have to alter all your tables.

Comment: A common technique would be to create an identical table structure with the new collation and then do a INSERT INTO new_table_name SELECT * from old_table_name.  Then you can inspect the results of the collation change.

Comment: In the conversion I got errors in the enums when I have at least, the character ç and/or ã.

Comment: A Collation have the same characteristics as ENUM: You cannot shift the order with impunity ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6966/877 )