# PROCEDURE ANALYSE suggests to turn timestamp into CHAR(19)

Tags: mysql, datatypes, datetime, varchar, enum

Using `Procedure Analyse()` under MySQL 5.6.30 on a table with about 4 million rows makes the following recommendations:

1. change **timestamp** to **char(19)**
2. **tinyint** to **ENUM**  (I noticed it's overzealous with ENUMS in general)
3. change **varchar** to **char(N)**

I can see the point of changing `varchar` to char when appropriate, but the first two recommendations strike me as odd. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> change timestamp to char(19)

String comparison is more streamlined and accurate that comparing a timestamp that may/may not include taking timezone into account. As a super bizzare example, see the [StackOverflow post from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/491757).

> tinyint to ENUM (I noticed it's overzealous with ENUMS in general)

`TINYINT` is a integer with the range -128 to 127

This gives you 256 distinct values that can be represented.

An `ENUM` can represent 256 times more values (65536 distinct values).

If the number of distinct values your table has for the `TINYINT` is huge (more that 10), [`PROCEDURE ANALYSE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/procedure-analyse.html) is simply suggesting `ENUM` in the event the number of distinct values will rise in the future. Internally, an `ENUM` will go from 1 byte to 2 bytes should the number of distinct values has to exceed 256 (See [`Data Type Storage Requirements` under the heading `Storage Requirements for String Types`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) for more info).

If you never have to increase the number of distinct values, you can ignore this suggestion.

I beg you to never use `ENUM` anyway : See my post [Advantages and Disadvantages to using ENUM vs Integer types?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types/6966#6966)

> change varchar to char(N)

This depends on your need for speed or space

- `VARCHAR` is great for a table to be more compact
- `CHAR` us better for speed when doing string comparison and processing
- See my posts

  - `May 10, 2011` : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)
  - `Mar 25, 2011` : [Performance implications of MySQL VARCHAR sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/424/performance-implications-of-mysql-varchar-sizes/1915#1915)

Following this suggestion (or not) is totally at your discretion

Comment: I added answers to those two links, in an attempt to get them more in line with current versions.

Answer (score 1):

`CHAR` has a nasty side.  `ANALYSE()` predates character sets, and its code was probably not updated to take into account that English text in `CHAR(...) utf8mb4` wastes 3/4 of the space!  Also, there was some utility of MyISAM row_format=fixed, but such is now useless in the default InnoDB.

Bottom line:  ignore its advice about `CHAR` unless you (1) really have fixed length strings and (2) have specified an appropriate `CHARACTER SET`.

I would not change `TIMESTAMP` to `CHAR(19)` because (1) the explosion of space due to utf8, and (2) you would lose the timezone adjustment that exists *currently* in the table, and (3) `CHAR(19)` is a lot bigger than the footprint of `TIMESTAMP` (4 bytes previously, now 5-8), and (4) `ANALYSE()` probably has not been updated to understand microseconds.

`DATETIME`, on the other hand does not have the timezone issue.  But points 1,3,4 still apply.

Comment: Bug created: [PROCEDURE ANALYSE() is antiquated](http://bugs.mysql.com/82086)