# MySQL: optimize column size

Tags: mysql, optimization, tools, size

I need a tool/command which will check a table then say something like that:

- columnA use tinyint instead of int
- columnB use enum instead of varchar

I've seen something like this while ago so I do know it exists, but search gives nothing or I'm asking it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

This is such a quick and dirty question.

This deserves a quick and dirty answer.

Good News : [PROCEDURE ANALYSE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html)

Bad News : It is Deprecated in 5.7.18 and will not be available in MySQL 8.0

I have discussed  [PROCEDURE ANALYSE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html) over the years: [See my old posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20PROCEDURE%20ANALYSE()).

In your case, you would just do this:

```
SELECT columnA,columnB FROM yourtable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

and the output will tell you the min value, max value, avg value, and recommended datatype.

Comment: Sorry, does not work properly for me (Aurora 5,6): for example I have a table with 76776 records and varchar(255) field. It suggests to use for that field enum of 26812 values! What am I doing wrong? I've checked this your answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141841/procedure-analyse-suggests-to-turn-timestamp-into-char19/141868#141868 but still lost :( select * from my_table  PROCEDURE ANALYSE(1000000,2560000)

Comment: If the field is a `VARCHAR`, then `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` treats it as such. Replacing a VARCHAR full of numbers with an ENUM is expected behavior since an ENUM can represent 65535 distinct values. 26812 seems to fit within an ENUM.

Comment: If the `VARCHAR` column is full of integer values, that column should be converted to INT UNSIGNED. Then, run `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` again.

Comment: it is not integers but log lines: text+numbers. Is there better way?

Comment: it responds with ENUM to any and all column of every table I have regardless of type and amount of content :(

Answer (score 1):

For *huge* tables, the main part of performance is I/O.  The smaller the datatypes are, the less I/O is needed.

When laying out a schema, think about

- Use the smallest `...INT` that can safely hold the possible values.  Most people blindly use the 4-byte `INT`, even for true/false flags.  Some products blindly use the 8-byte `BIGINT`.  `BIGINT` is not justified 98% of the time.
- Use `UNSIGNED` when appropriate (which is most of the time).
- Do not blindly say `VARCHAR(255)` for strings.
- There is a 3-way battle between `ENUM`, `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, and `VARCHAR`; each has advantages and disadvantages.  The first two are only 1 byte.
- Indexes take space, too, and have copies of the columns.  But that is another large discussion.  Indexes are worth having, but don't blindly "index every column".
- Use the appropriate `CHARACTER SET`.
- Use `CHAR` only for truly fixed-length strings.  Such are almost always `CHARACTER SET ascii` -- think country_code, postal_code, etc.
- Never use `TINYTEXT`.  (The other sizes of `TEXT` are useful.)

It is good to get into the habit of using smaller datatypes, even for non-huge tables.

For tables that I write, I "know" what size the ints are / will be.  Without `PROCEDURE ANALYSE`, I simply say `SELECT MIN(a), MAX(a) ...` for numbers; `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(s)) ...` for `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`, *but* I add a fudge factor for future strings.