# MySQL schema design - how to decide between an `enum` vs. a table join

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

In designing a MySQL schema, **should I avoid using an `enum` type altogether**, as I have been reading really strong, but favored opinions on this subject, such as:

- [Stackoverflow post on efficiency of enum vs a join](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298472/is-it-wasteful-to-create-a-new-database-table-instead-of-using-enum-data-type)
- [`enum` is data, not code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305148/why-would-you-store-an-enum-in-db)
- [Blog: Reason why MySQL's enum data type is evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)
- [Right time to use an `enum`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/what-is-the-right-time-to-use-an-enum-versus-a-normalized-types-table-in-mysql)

Or, is there a choice to be made specific to the use case in hand? **If there is, what decision framework should I use, i.e. when to choose one of the two options?**

For instance:

- `Currency`: It's better to use a table join, since currency codes to be supported could change with time (since modification has been emphasized in many posts as anti-enum, **but then what could not change with time?**).
- `PaymentStatus`: It's better to use `enum` type with values like, `SUCCESS`, `FAILED`, `CANCELLED`.
- `TierPlans`: It's better to use a table join, as it would give the flexibility to add columns like monthlyPricing, annualPricing, discountRate, etc. in the future. (I am currently using `enum` instead, with values like `FREE`, `PRO`, `MASTER`; hadn't thought of pricing yet -_- ).

> *I am finding that if I stress enough, I could find a table join being a better choice always, mutation safe route.* **Is increasing number of tables or table joins a symptom of bad design? How should I approach
>   design in general, and design in such use cases specifically?**

---

Note: I had asked this question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694154/mysql-schema-design-how-to-decide-between-an-enum-vs-a-table-join). I am posting it here since I see that there is a closing request there, and I desperately need an answer to this confusing roadblock of mine. Understandably this might not be a good question to ask here too. I'd rather edit, if you may guide!

Comment: Don't confuse the issues re MySQL enum specifically with the issue of numbers vs readable representations (eg strings + enums). Please do not cross post within [se] sites. [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3404097)

Comment: Hi @philipxy, I have deleted my question from there, and I would admit that I should have posted this here in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

(Yes, there have been many heated discussions of ENUM vs TINYINT vs VARCHAR, both here and on stackoverflow.com.  I have put my 2-cents in on some of them.  I am addressing this Question to discuss nuances of the examples brought up.)

Currency is a tricky one.  When, for example, a devaluation occurs, does the currency_code change?

If so, then is the question is about how often the list of values is likely to change.

If it does not change, then you may have a mess for the data -- Is "XYZ", the old xyz currency, or the 'new'?

With things like country_code (with well-established 2-letter codes) and currency_code (3 letter standard), etc, I recommend using things like

```
country_code  CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
currency_code CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

Rationale:

- Only 2 or 3 bytes, which is not much bigger than a 1-byte `ENUM` or `TINYINT`.
- Avoids the extra bulk and overhead of utf8mb4, which might be the default for the table.
- You can still build a secondary table to, for example, spell out the full name of the country or currency.
- You won't need a `JOIN` except when you want the extra info.  (`JOINing` is most costly when you need to *start* from multiple Dimension tables in an attempt to look up rows in the Fact table.  A `JOIN` is reasonably cheap going the other direction.)

Comment: Hi @Rick, thanks for your answer. But I don't really take away: "when should I not use a table join, and use enum instead?". Also, in your elaborate example, why do I need secondary table for keep description, can't it be just another column in our currency table, with country code as primary key?

Comment: @devautor - Oops, I did not think about currency simply living on the Country code row.  Another example:  If you already 'normalize' city, don't bother normalizing state or country; simply spell them out (or use abbrev) in the city table.

Comment: Hi @Rick, got this last point on normalization, thanks :) I feel bad to press, but do you feel this answers already: "Should I never use enum, or when should I not?"

Comment: I like ENUMs in some situations.  Some people insist that ENUMs should _never_ be used.  The two camps are too rational and too vocal for this to have a simple answer.  Another "rule" for `ENUMs`:  Don't use if there are more than 2 options.  (I would stretch that to more like 5 options.)  Would you dare have a column `gender ENUM('male', 'female')` when registering people at an LGBTIQA+ convention?  Either avoid Enum, or be ready to add yet another option.

Comment: Makes sense! I think the general rule of thumb could be then that locally related and immutable list of up to 5 values is for `enum`.