# What data type should I use: ENUM, TINYINT, or CHAR?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I'm creating a new table and I would like to do it right. The table will be a list of members with their Professional Type and Decile associated.

The Professional Type is a 3-character string. There are only 8 allowable strings for this field. Should I use ENUM or CHAR(3) or something better?

The Decile can be any number between 1-10, but only these numbers. Should I use ENUM or unsigned TINYINT or something better?

Which are the best options for efficiency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ENUMs scare me because of any issue regarding adding/removing type values. You are probably better off representing both `ProfessionalType` and `Decile` as `TINYINT` or `CHAR(3)`. Anything but ENUM.

See my past posts on `ENUM` :

- `Ocy 19, 2011` : [Advantages and Disadvantages to using ENUM vs Integer types?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types/6966#6966)
- `Jan 24, 2012` : [Is it possible to change ENUM() lists?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/is-it-possible-to-change-enum-lists/11485#11485)

For efficiency, please do not index this field alone, given such a low cardinality (8,10).

Comment: agreed. just want to add as well, if you're using an ORM like Hibernate it'll likely be an extra big PITA since `ENUM` isn't a standard SQL datatype

Answer (score 3):

I would add one more thing to all the previous answers and linked questions. It happened to me that I had a tinyint column to represent boolean. But one day I needed to split the `true` value to two separate values. Extending `0,1` to `0,1,2` was trivial, whereas changing it to string-enum would require more effort. Also reverting tinyint-enum of three values back to tinyint-boolean would be similarly easy.

Comment: while this is certainly a handy tip for MySQL, not all databases treat booleans as integers (like Postgres for example).

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain about having no more than 10 types, then use `ENUM`. Otherwise use a `TINYINT`, possibly pointing to a small table mapping these values to acceptable names/descriptions.

Avoid using `CHAR(3)`; it is lengthier and prone to confusion (case sensitive? no? indexes are worse when insensitive).